# XSLT Format Date

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, string-formatting

I have a date in this format

```
10/12/2011 12:55:00 PM (MM-DD-YYYY time)
```

I would like to format this date into

```
12/10/2011 (DD-MM-YYYY) time to be removed
```

using XSLT? the complexity I find is sometimes the input date can look like

```
7/12/2011 12:55:00 PM (only one number to the front instead of 07)
```

Can someone please show me a way to implement this? many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to obtain desired result using only standard XPath string functions like `substring-before`, `substring-after` and `substring`, e.g.:

```
<xsl:variable name="input">7/12/2011 12:55:00 PM</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="concat(
              substring-before(substring-after($input, '/'), '/'), '/',
              substring-before($input, '/'), '/',
              substring(substring-after(substring-after($input, '/'), '/'), 1, 4)
              )"/>
```

Comment: You might want to double-check AU/US date ordering here - there was a suggested edit that copied and swapped the second and third lines with a note that it put it in Australian (dmy) order. The edit looked valid to me, but was rejected.